# How to display pagination using jquery dom in datatable?

Tags: jquery, html, datatables, pagination

---

In the below code I would like to display the pagination using jQuery dom.But when I inserting `"sDom": 'fl<t>ip'` my total table was getting dissappeared. Someone kindly help me.

---

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
                var oTable;
                var _sid;
                oTable = $("#studentTable").dataTable({
                    "aLengthMenu": [
                                       [5, 10, 25, 50, -1],
                                       [5, 10, 25, 50, "All"]
                    ],
                    // set the initial value
                    "bAutoWidth": true,
                    "bScrollCollapse": true,

                    "iDisplayLength": 5,

                    "sDom": 'fl<t>ip',

                    "bJQueryUI": false,
                    "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
                    "oLanguage": {
                        "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_ records per page",
                        "oPaginate": {
                            "sPrevious": "Prev",
                            "sNext": "Next"
                    },
                    },
                    "bServerSide": true,
                    "sAjaxSource": "GetStudentList",
                    "bProcessing": true,
                    "bDestroy": true,
                    "aoColumns": [
                            {
                                "sName": "StudentId"
                            },
                            {
                                "sName": "FirstName"
                            },
                            {
                                "sName": "LastName"
                            },
                            {
                                "sName": "Grade"
                            },
                            {
                                "sName": "School"
                            },
                            {
                                "sName": "Status"
                            },
                            {
                                "data": "StudentId", "width": "50px", "render": function (data) {
                                    return '<a class="edit" href="">Edit</a>';
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "data": "StudentId", "width": "50px", "render": function (data) {
                                    return '<a class="delete" href="">Delete</a>';
                                }

                            }
                    ]
                });
```

Here `p` is a pagination controll. But why it was not working?